# AngularJS ng-repeat filtering with an OR-statement

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

So I have a dataset of companies stored in a variable in a controller.

```
$scope.companies = [
    {
        name: "first company",
        type: ["a", "b"]
    },
    {
        name: "second company",
        type: ["b"]
    },
    {   
        name: "third company",
        type: ["c"]
    }
]
```

Then i have my list where I want to list all companies of either a or b. I thought sending and array would work as an or-statement. Turns out it's more like an and-statement.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="company in companies | filter:filters{type: ['a', 'b']}">
        {{company.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

The code above would list "first company" while I would like it to list both the "first company" and the "second company". I know I could manipulate the $scope.companies dataset from within the controller, but I'd like to know if there's any "native" way to achieve this first.

Best regards!
// Richard

Answer (score 12):

Your only options is to use a filter using a function:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="company in companies | filter:customFunction">
        {{company.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where

```
$scope.customFunction = function(item){ /* true if you want item, false if not */ }
```

Source: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter#parameters

Comment: Thanks! Much more elegant than permutations of the dataset. Also thanks for the source!

Comment: Thanks ! @RichardLilja why didn't you validate this answer as being the solution to your question ? It makes it rank higher in search engines for searches matching your problem, would have helped me find this elegant solution before wasting time making a custom filter